# Completable future waste more time?

Tags: java, java-8, completable-future

I have a question, I am learning about CompletableFuture of Java 8, I did a dummy with One method running with runAsync of Completable future, it is a simple for 0 to 10 and in paralen a for o to 5 In the second method I run the same for to 0 to 20, but the method of runAsyn takes longer than the other method, It is normal?

Shouldn't the asynchronous method last the same or less than the other method?

**Here is the code.**

```
public class Sample{

public static void main(String x[]) throws InterruptedException {
    
    runAsync();
    System.out.println("========== SECOND TESTS ==========");
    runSync();
}

static void runAsync() throws InterruptedException {
    long startTimeOne = System.currentTimeMillis();

    CompletableFuture<Void> cf = CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10L; i++) {
            System.out.println(" Async One");
        }
    });
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        System.out.println("two");
    }
    System.out.println("It is ready One? (1) " + cf.isDone());
    System.out.println("It is ready One? (2)" + cf.isDone());
    System.out.println("It is ready One? (3)" + cf.isDone());
    System.out.println("It is ready One? (4)" + cf.isDone());
    System.out.println("It is ready One? (5)" + cf.isDone());
    System.out.println("It is ready One? (6)" + cf.isDone());
    long estimatedTimeOne = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTimeOne;
    System.out.println("Total time async: " + estimatedTimeOne);

}

static void runSync() {
    long startTimeTwo = System.currentTimeMillis();

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        System.out.println("No async");
    }
    long estimatedTimeTwo = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTimeTwo;
    System.out.println("Total time no async: " + estimatedTimeTwo);

}
```

}

The normal for waste **1 milisecond** and the runAsync waste **54 miliseconds**

[**Here is the result screenshot**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hVXzD.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you're dealing with numbers as tiny as 5 and 10, doing CPU-bound work and printing to output, async is totally pointless. You'll need to find an appropriate use case for it before it makes any sense to benchmark.

Comment: You will never get a faster result if you wait for the completion of your async task. Async does nothing faster than sync, it simply does it a-synchronous, meaning that your current thread can do stuff while sone other code runs

Answer (score 2):

First, you are violating basic rules mentioned in [How do I write a correct micro-benchmark in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/504103/2711488)

Most notably, you’re running both approaches within the same runtime and allow them to affect each other.

Besides that, you are getting an output that is a sequence of messages, which is showing the fundamental problem of your operation: you can not print concurrently. The output system itself has to ensure that the printing will end up showing a sequential behavior.

When you are performing actions that can’t run in parallel through a concurrent framework, you can’t gain performance, you can only add thread communication overhead.

Besides that, the operations are not even the same:

- the action you are passing to `runAsync` uses `10L` as end boundary, in other words, is performing a `long` comparison where all other loops use `int`
- `"It is ready One? (6)" + cf.isDone()` is performing two operations that do not appear in the sequential variant. First, polling the status of the `CompletableFuture`, which must be done with inter-thread semantics. Second, it bears string concatenation. Both are potentially expensive operations
- The async variant is printing 21 messages whereas the sequential is printing 20. Even the total amount of characters to print is roughly 50% more in the async operation

These points may serve as examples of how easily you can do things wrong in a manual benchmark.  But they do not affect the outcome significantly, due to the fundamental aspect mentioned before them. You can’t gain a performance advantage of doing the printing asynchronously at all.

Note that the output is quite consistent in your specific case. Since the common Fork/Join thread pool has not been used before your asynchronous operation, it needs to start a new thread when you submit your job, which takes so long that the subsequent local loop printing `"two"` completes before the asynchronous operation even starts. The next operation, polling `cf.isDone()` and performing string concatenation, on the other hand, is so slow, that the asynchronous operation completes entirely before these six print statements complete.

When you change the code to

```
CompletableFuture<Void> cf = CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        System.out.println("Async One");
    }
});
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    System.out.println("two");
}
cf.join();
```

you still can’t get a performance advantage, but the performance difference will be much smaller. When you add a statement like

```
ForkJoinPool.commonPool().execute(() -> System.out.println());
```

at the beginning of the `main` method, to ensure that the thread pool does not need to get initialized within the measured method, the perceived overhead may even reduce further.

Further, you may swap the order of the `runAsync();` and `runSync();` method invocations in the `main` method, to see how first-time execution effects influence the result when you run the two methods within the same JVM.

This all is not enough to make it a reliable benchmark but should help to understand the things that will go wrong when not understanding the pitfalls of doing a micro-benchmark.